# wp_get_attachment_image_src on multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains, images, cropping

I try to get cropped image `src` on my subdomain multisite, but not working. My code here:

```
// avatar uploader
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'bwpy_logo2', array(
    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint', 
    'default'           => ''
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'bwpy_logo2', array(
    'label'       => __( 'Site Avatar', 'bwpy' ),
    'section'     => 'title_tagline',
    'settings'    => 'bwpy_logo2',
    'flex-width'  => true,
    'width'       => 300,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'height'      => 300,
    'priority'    => 21
) ) );
```

And this is, how I try to get this in the current theme header:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( absint( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="header-avatar">
    <?php else : ?>
    <img src="default-site-icon.png" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="header-avatar">
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Why not working this?

the output scr this: Array so:
`<img src="Array" alt="Blog Title" class="header-avatar">`

Comment: please edit your questtion and be explicit what you mean when you say "not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function returns an array that's why your code isn't working. Try the following code.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) :
        $img_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( absint( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) );
        $img_url = isset( $img_data[0] ) ? $img_data[0] : '';
        // Or you can try this
        // $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( absint( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) );
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_url ); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="header-avatar">
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="default-site-icon.png" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" class="header-avatar">
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: If I use `$img_url = isset( $img_data[0] ) : $img_data[0] : '';` than I get an unexpected error, but with `img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( absint( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) );` works perfect! Thank you so much, I suffered with this for more than 3 hours in all!

Comment: Sorry there was a syntax error. Supposed to be this `isset( $img_data[0] ) ? $img_data[0] : '';`. Btw glad to hear that it worked.

Comment: Great, thus works! I would add more, the `wp_get_attachment_image_url` has $size value and this 'thumbnail' in default (150x150px), so I completed the code accordingly:
`if ( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) ) :
     $absint = absint( get_theme_mod( 'bwpy_logo2' ) );
        $img_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $absint, $size = 'medium' );
        $img_url = isset( $img_data[0] ) ? $img_data[0] : '';`
More alternative img sizes here: [https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails]